# Why matroid cannot have S in I?

Tags: combinatorics, matroids, linear-independence

I'm learning matroids for algorithm analysis. Definition of a matroid is as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid),

In terms of independence, a finite matroid M is a pair (E,I), where E is a finite set (called the ground set) and I is a family of subsets of E (called the independent sets) with the following properties:

(I1) The empty set is independent, i.e., ∅ ∈ I.

(I2) Every subset of an independent set is independent, i.e., for each A′⊆ A ⊆ E, if
A ∈ I, then A` ∈ I. This is sometimes called the hereditary property, or the downward-closed property.

(I3) If A and B are two independent sets (i.e., each set is independent) and A has more elements than B, then there exists x ∈ A\B such that B ∪ {x} is in I.

This is sometimes called the augmentation property or the independent set exchange property.
The first two properties define a combinatorial structure known as an independence system (or abstract simplicial complex).

My problem is if S = {1,2,3,4} and M is a matroid (S,I). Then can we have {1,2,3,4} ∈ I ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In general, given a finite set $E$, if we let $2^E$ be the set of all subsets of $E$, then $M=(E,2^E)$ is a matroid, called the [free matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_matroid) on $E$. Notice that if $M=(E,\mathcal I)$ and $E\in\mathcal I$, then immediately by the hereditary property we must have $\mathcal I=2^E$.

Comment: Its a clear answer. What is the meaning of independence in terms of a matroid? Is E independent in this case?

Comment: Yes, $E$ is independent since $E\in\mathcal I$. In a matroid $M=(E,\mathcal I)$, any element of $\mathcal I$ is said to be *independent*. This terminology arises from the fact that a matroid generalizes and abstracts the idea of linear independence from linear algebra; in particular, given a set of vectors $E=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ in $\mathbb R^d$, if we let $\mathcal I$ be the set of linearly independent subsets of $E$, then $(E,\mathcal I)$ is a matroid.